# Facebook PHP SDK: How to get $helper->getSessionFromRedirect() to return a valid session

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK to log a user in, but when the user returns from the Facebook login URL, after signing in, `$helper->getSessionFromRedirect()` returns `NULL`, instead of with a valid session.

I've followed [Facebook's docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/4.0.0), read the answers and comments on these similar questions:

- php facebook login getSessionFromRedirect is null (I don't have enough rep points to post links to all of them)
- Facebook php sdk: getSessionFromRedirect returns null
- Why is facebook's getSessionFromRedirect() method returning NULL despite a user having logged in?

And I found [other solutions](http://www.benmarshall.me/facebook-sdk-php-v4/) around the web, and my code matches solutions others say work for them, but I'm missing something.

I have my Facebook app setup, and the Site URL and App Domain set to the URL the app is on.

I have two pages in place.

On the first is the 'Login with Facebook' link.

And the second handles the response from Facebook, and should start the user's session.

Here's the code for the login page:

```
session_start();

// using Composer
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

$app_id = 'my_id';
$app_secret = 'my_secret';
$redirect_url = 'my_redirect_url';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
```

And here's the code for the second page, to receive the response after logging in, `app.php`.

```
session_start();

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

$app_id = 'my_id';
$app_secret = 'my_secret';
$redirect_url = 'my_redirect_url';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

var_dump($helper);
```

This is what I get from `var_dump($helper)`, notice `session: NULL` at the end:

```
object(Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper)#2 (6) { ["appId":"Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper":private]=> string(16) "my_id" ["appSecret":"Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper":private]=> string(32) "my_secret" ["redirectUrl":"Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper":private]=> string(32) "my_redirect_url" ["sessionPrefix":"Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper":private]=> string(6) "FBRLH_" ["state":protected]=> string(32) "a_32_character_string" ["checkForSessionStatus":protected]=> bool(true) } session: NULL
```

Any help would be awesome. This is my first question also, so if I can do anything to improve it, let me know.

Comment: First of all, check if your PHP session is picked up again as expected.

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks for the reply. It looks like the session is being picked up. On the first page, I set a random variable and `var_dump($_SESSION)` gives me:

`array(1) {
  ["favcolor"]=>
  string(5) "green"
}`

On the second page, after login, `var_dump` gives me:

array(2) {
  ["favcolor"]=>
  string(5) "green"
  ["FBRLH_state"]=>
  string(32) "long_random_number"
}